# Composite of field extension isomorphic to tensor product of field extensions imply linear independence

Tags: abstract-algebra, commutative-algebra, field-theory, galois-theory

This is problem 6.7 of Lorenz, *Algebra I*. I have solved the problem by one way but I want to try something else.

Let $E_1/K,E_2/K$ be finite extension and $E_1E_2$ be the composite field of $E_1,E_2$. Show $E_1E_2\cong E_1\otimes E_2$ (as $K$-algebras) if and only if $E_1E_2:E_1=E_2:K$.

I want to prove the direction $E_1E_2\cong E_1\otimes E_2\implies E_1E_2:E_1=E_2:K$

The tensor product here means as $K$-module. This is trivially done by assuming $E_1=K^n,E_2=K^m$, then $E_1\otimes E_2\cong K^{mn}$ which finishes everything.

1. I want to prove the statement by [equational criterion of flatness](http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/00HK). How should I do it? Clearly if $E_1E_2:E_1<E_2:K$, somehow my gut tells me that $E_2$ cannot be a flat $K$-module.
2. Does this statement hold when either extensions are not finite?

Comment: Isn't every finite-dimensional vector space over a field free, hence flat?

Comment: @Quasicoherent Oh. In this case, yes. I forgot the most basic fact. It is flat. So for infinite case, I need left coherence then? Shouldn't left coherence obvious?

Comment: I guess I shouldn't have mentioned finite dimensionality: every vector space (even if it is infinite-dimensional) has a basis, hence is free.  I think you may have this backwards: if $E_2$ were not flat, then $E_1 \otimes_K E_2$ would be "too small."  But it's not, since $E_1\otimes E_2\cong K^{mn}$ as you stated.  Rather, it's $E_1 E_2$ that is "too small," since if $E_1E_2:E_1<E_2:K$ then $\operatorname{dim}_K(E_1 E_2) < mn$.

Comment: Another way to think about it: we always have the surjection $\varphi: E_1 \otimes E_2 \to E_1 E_2$, $a \otimes b \mapsto ab$, so $\text{dim}_K(E_1 \otimes E_2) \geq \text{dim}_K(E_1 E_2)$.  If $E_1$ and $E_2$ are linearly disjoint (so $E_1 E_2:E_1 = E_2:K$), then $\varphi$ is also injective.

Comment: Quasicoherent hit the nail on the head. The key here is not flatness but rather linear disjointness. The problem you want to avoid is $E_1E_2$ being too small. The standard example is that of $K=\Bbb{Q}$, $E_1=K(\root3\of2)$, $E_2=K(e^{2\pi i/3}\root3\of2)$. Both $E_1$ and $E_2$ are 3-dimensional $K$-spaces but the compositum $E_1E_2=K(\root3\of2,e^{2\pi i/3})$ is the splitting field of $x^3-2$ and only a $6$-dimensional $K$-space.

Comment: Or, viewed differently, it is not easy to ascertain that $E_1\otimes E_2$ would be a field!! In the finite case this amounts to the following. If $E_1=K(a)$, and $p(x)$ is the minimal polynomial of $a$, then $E_1\simeq K[x]/I, I=\langle p(x)\rangle$. Flatness of $E_2$ applied to the short exact sequence
$$0\to I\to K[x]\to E_1\to0$$
gives $E_1\otimes E_2\simeq E_2[x]/I_2$, where $I_2$ is the ideal of $E_2[x]$ generated by $p(x)$. In this case $E_1\otimes E_2$ is thus a field if and only if $p(x)$ is irreducible also as an element of $E_2[x]$.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen Is there a good way to tell whether tensor product of reduced algebra is a field? Tensor product of finitely generated reduced algebra is reduced. Is there example of infinite tensor product of reduced algebras is not reduced? Can I think of this as taking direct limit of systems with restriction mapping as $\prod_{i\leq m}A_i\to \prod_{i\leq m+1}A_i$ by canonical map?

Comment: @user45765 It's not true that the tensor product of finitely generated reduced algebras over a field is reduced. Let $p$ be a prime and take $K = \mathbb F_p(t)$ and $L = K(\sqrt[p]{t}) \cong K[x]/(x^p-t)$, then $L \otimes_{K} L \cong L \otimes_K K[x]/(x^p-t) \cong L[x]/(x^p-t) = L[x]/(x-\sqrt[p]{t})^p$, which is obviously not reduced.

Comment: @MatheiBoulomenos Yes. In that case, I need algebraic closureness of the ground field. Or it does not work.

Comment: @user45765 You don't need algebraic closedness, it's enough to assume that the ground field is perfect.

Comment: @MatheiBoulomenos Thanks a lot.